# How many, of a given weekday there has been since the beginning of this month?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a date, and I would like to find out how many, of this weekday, there has been since the beginning of this month. (should be 1-5)

The reason I need this number is because I am telling customers I will deliver something on "the 4rd Wednesday of the month" for example.

I do not need something that just returns the number of weeks it has been starting from a predefined beginning day of week (every example I can find does just that).

It may help to know that I have implemented the reverse of this code as follows:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2013-08 4 Wednesday")); 
//returns the 4th Wednesday of the month namely "2013-08-28"
```

How can I get the "4" starting with "2013-08-28"?

Comment: oh come on!! did you even bother to check the manual for date() ?

Comment: That's **"Wednesday"** and not `Wedneday` ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like this should work with minimal changes to your code.

```
<?php
$d = date('d', strtotime("2013-08-28")); 
echo ceil($d/7).PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Outputs '4'. I'm sure you can wrap it in a function.

[ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)

Comment: Or how about `date('w', $time) + 1` ?!

Comment: @onetrickpony: Typo? `echo date('w', strtotime('2013-12-28'))+1;` outputs 7.

Comment: logically it was a lot easier than i had thought. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a crack at this one... I think if you take the number of the month returned by the PHP date() function, divide by 7 and ceil(), it gives you the right number (I just compared to my calendar, so not 100% it's guarenteed).  The following code contains a function and runs a test loop at the end that produces the following output

2nd Mon of the month
2nd Tue of the month
2nd Wed of the month
3th Thu of the month
3th Fri of the month
3th Sat of the month
3th Sun of the month
3th Mon of the month
3th Tue of the month
3th Wed of the month
4th Thu of the month
4th Fri of the month
4th Sat of the month
4th Sun of the month
4th Mon of the month
4th Tue of the month

```
<?php

   function getDateString($time) {
     date_default_timezone_set ( "America/Los_Angeles" );
     //$time = time();
     $which_day = ceil((int) date('j', $time) / 7);
     $which_day_name = date('D', $time);

     $suffix = 'st';
     switch ($which_day) {
       case 2 : 
         $suffix = 'nd';
         break;
       case 3 :
       case 4 :
       case 5 :
         $suffix = 'th';
         break;
     }   

     return $which_day . $suffix . ' ' . $which_day_name . ' of the month ' . PHP_EOL;
   }


   $time = time();
   echo getDateString($time);
   foreach (range(0, 15) as $day) {
     $time = time() + ($day * 24 * 60 * 60);
     echo getDateString($time);
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, alternatively ...

```
function getHowManyOfWeekday($d) { 
  $g = getdate($d);
  return ceil($g['mday'] / 7) + 1;
}

// Some tests ... 
echo getHowManyOfWeekday(strtotime("2013-08-07")). "\n";
echo getHowManyOfWeekday(strtotime("2013-08-11")). "\n";
echo getHowManyOfWeekday(strtotime("2013-08-18")). "\n";
echo getHowManyOfWeekday(strtotime("2013-08-19")). "\n";
echo getHowManyOfWeekday(strtotime("2013-08-31")). "\n";
```